# Android SQLite equivalent of the given update query

Tags: android, sqlite

I have to execute the following query in **Android SQLite**

```
UPDATE player SET rank=rank+1 WHERE rank >= 3;
```

Here **rank** is the column name of **INTEGER** type.

I know about update method

```
update(tablename, values, whereClause, whereArgs);
```

I will pass **player** as **first argument**, **rank >= 3** as **3rd argument** and **null** as **last argument** but I am unable to find what to pass as **2nd argument**. According to the docs it should be an object of **ContentValues**.

so I created its object as

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("rank",?????);
```

I am confused about what to put the value for **rank** key which is a column in my table. Please suggest me what to pass as value to **put() method of values**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe **update** method is not *One-Size-Fit-All* method. So I think you need to use **rawQuery()** to achieve this kind of sql execution. for example:

```
db.rawQuery("UPDATE player SET rank=rank+1 WHERE rank >= 3;", null);
```

*or perhaps use execSQL as said by el7r*

Answer (score 5):

alternatively you can use exec , and execute your sql command

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE player SET rank=rank+1 WHERE rank >= 3");
```

to do it using the update method, you will need to get the current rank in a variable using Cursor, and then do the + thing manually "current+1"